# Convert this JavaScript code to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery, so I'm having trouble solving this. I want this converted to jQuery.

**JavaScript:**

```
var el = document.getElementById("box");
el.style.backgroundColor = "#0000000";
var new_el = document.createElement("div");
new_el.innerHTML = "<p>some content</p>";
el.appendChild(new_el);
```

Comment: You'll get better responses if you provide your attempt so far.

Comment: `$('#box').css('background','black').append('<div><p>some content</p></div>');`

Comment: @JaredFarrish, why provide the answer as a comment?

Comment: @Dancrumb - I'm lazy at the moment and the comment box was *right there*.

Comment: @LordFaim  You will probably get several answers and I bet most will be valid ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var $el = $('#box');
$el.css('background-color', '#000000');

$('<div><p>some content</p></div>').appendTo($el);
```

Comment: Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/9qWTe/

Comment: Chaining would also work, although demonstrating caching is also useful.

Comment: You are right it could be written differently and all chained together. I tried to do it in a similar way to the javascript so that it would make sense to the OP.  Of course We could `append` instead of `appendTo` as well... etc